# rseq vs. reverse in clojure

Tags: clojure, reverse

What are the differences of `rseq` `reverse` in the examples provided in [the manual](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rseq) of `rseq`? One gets the same result using `reverse` instead of `rseq` in the examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rseq` is potentially faster (constant time) than `reverse` but the catch is that it can only be used on vectors and sorted-maps.

Comment: What does constant time mean?

Comment: constant time means the performance does not depend on the size of the data structure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that `reverse` takes linear time and that `rseq` is essentially lazy.

Comment: How can reversing a whole sequence be constant time? Does Clojure indexed sequences have a direction field or something?

Comment: @Sylwester a "sequence" is a generic interface that is implemented differently for different collections. `reverse` returns a list (which is  "accidentally" a "sequence", but it's just an implementation) with the given sequence reversed. `rseq` returns a lazy sequence with no particular guarantees on the time it will take to evaluate its elements.

Comment: @D-side But my point is that all of them would do it in O(n) time. At the easiest point you might make a collection that iterates in reverse and you just wrap the original collection. Then you'd be calling that accessor `n` times if you used all `n` elements , thus forcing the computation. It's stlll O(n).

Comment: @Sylwester it's traversal that's O(n), but `rseq` doesn't actually traverse that collection. It's the caller of `rseq` that does it afterwards.